# Enforcing process/thread priority in the face of resource starvation

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, process, timer

My application must ping a (lan) server every 30 seconds in order to let it know I'm alive.

This works fine, except for when a separate process I do not control uses a very large amount of system resources and hangs the entire machine while it does its thing. As a result, my timer tick is delayed until the other process finishes its heavy lifting, and by this time the server already believes I have died.

The other process is set at low priority, and my process is set at normal priority.

My first attempt used a `System.Timers.Timer` to initiate the ping.

In a second attempt, I tried to roll my own `PriorityTimer`, to run on a dedicated high priority thread, but that also seems to have little effect.

```
public sealed class PriorityTimer : IDisposable
{
    private int interval;
    private bool active;

    private Thread timerThread;
    private AutoResetEvent resetEvent;

    public event EventHandler Elapsed;

    public PriorityTimer(int interval)
    {
        this.interval = interval;
        resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    }

    public bool Enabled
    {
        get { return active; }
        set
        {
            if (active != value)
            {
                active = value;
                if (value)
                {
                    timerThread = new Thread(Wait);
                    timerThread.IsBackground = true;
                    timerThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
                    timerThread.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    resetEvent.Set();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Wait()
    {
        resetEvent.Reset();
        while (!resetEvent.WaitOne(interval))
        {
            if (Elapsed != null)
            {
                Elapsed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Assuming I can not force the offending process to play nice, what can I do to assure my timer elapses at 30 seconds?

Comment: How long does that other process hog the cpu?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It varies by the task it's doing (3d rendering). Somewhere in the range of 2 seconds to 10 minutes.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Also, the duration is higher when there is a high saturation of **RAM** in addition to CPU usage.

Comment: In any case, Windows is not a real time operating system, it has no guarantees about how quickly your timers/threads/code will get priority. Your best option, in my opinion, is to get that other process to play nice. Can you lower its priority?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's already at lowest priority, while my process is at `normal`, which makes me wonder why it's getting more slices than me.

Comment: Why do you think that if a process has "hanged" the machine other nodes shouldn't view it as not alive?

Comment: thread prioritization really can't do much *after the fact*  If something already has CPU, changing another thread's priority isn't going to take that CPU away.  And if your thread is voluntarily giving up priority (via the wait) then other threads can effectively continue to use CPU for their purposes.  There's no guarantee that `WaitOne` will timeout exactly on the timeout value you give it.  Windows is a sandbox that you have to share, you have to play nice and not expect to take precedence over anyone else in the sandbox when you see fit.

Comment: @Peter RE your first comment, spawning the heavy process is exactly my applications job (it's a network render manager), so it is actually doing what's it been asked to do, and should be considered alive.

Comment: That sounds pretty odd. Are you sure you didn't do something like spawn the process with a wait for its completion, and therefore your timer never starts? Also, are you sure that your `System.Timers.Timer` event handler isn't throwing an exception? If the event handler throws an exception, the Timer will squash it and the rest of your program will never know about it.

Comment: @Jim Definitely not the case on both accounts.

Comment: Paging IO is not subject to CPU priorities. Any idea involving CPU priorities will not help.

Comment: @usr That sounds right on the money, this does seem to happen when huge amounts of memory is paged to disk. Could you elaborate on that? Are there workarounds?

Comment: @JimMischel - is seems very odd to me, too.  IME, when a higher-priority thread becomes ready on Windows, it gets dispatched pretty quick. I have a couple apps where all 4/8 cores are at 100% with a lower-priority process and threads, but its normal-priority GUI works reasonably well.  I would have thought that a page-fault in the heavy process would be a good thing here - some thread has entered the OS and blocked on disk I/O, so freeing up a core without any inter-thread comms to force it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this does seem to happen when huge amounts of memory is paged to disk.

You can either try to keep your own working set in memory, or force the other (rogue) process(es) to consume less. The latter strategy is more reliable.

Create a [Windows Job Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and configure its maximum memory usage. Assign the problematic processes into the Job. Jobs are capable of limiting CPU usage and memory. They are meant to "jail" processes.

Comment: Thanks, I will give the latter a try, but could you explain what the former option ("keep your own working set in memory") means for a .NET application?

Comment: I'm not even sure that's possible. You can lock pages in memory, but only if you control the allocation code (which you don't with .NET). Windows has an API to set the working set size but I don't think that's reliable or works at all. I don't quite remember. Even if you manage to prevent being paged out, your process might rely on other processes that *are* paged out. IOW you have no good options to force your own working set to stay paged in.

Comment: There's also a thing called memory priority (https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=windows+set+memory+priority). It is quite new. You could try that. Still, it is better to not let paging kick in at all.

Answer (score 0):

Any operating system that doesn't enforce real-time constraints will generally miss timer requests by some normal delta under contention.  Have you been keeping track of your deltas?

Also, I would ask if you're using a garbage collected language.  If you are, pauses will definitely skew timer results.

Finally, what's the timer interval you're using to send the heartbeats?  As a general rule of thumb, you should send heartbeats twice every interval to account for timing variances.

Comment: The language is c# as mentioned in the tags. The timer should fire every 30 seconds. A slight delta is expected and tolerated. In fact, the server will tolerate up to 90 seconds, the problem is sometimes it doesn't fire for 5 minutes.

Comment: That suggests either the operating system scheduler follows a broken scheduling algorithm, *or* some other assumption is wrong.  Even if the process memory is being swapped to disk, the scheduler _should_ still give it cpu time.  If the scheduler isn't giving the process adequate cpu time due to swapping, a work around may be to lock pages into ram **mlockall** ?.  If the system is swapping heavily, you should probably increase the memory regardless though.  Last, another scheduler work around may be to set disjoint cpu affinities for the processes **pthread_setaffinity_np** ?.

Comment: I agree - it *should* still be getting cpu time, but for some reason it isn't. `mlockall` is linux, isn't it? And thread affinity is out of the question, the heavy process must have access to all cores.

Comment: POSIX, so it's most of the POSIX family (Linux, QNX, BSD, OSX, etc...). I'm almost certain there are equivalent system calls, I just don't know what they are. It sounds like windows job objects will give more control over scheduling and memory usage though. Possibly [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) has some userland utilities to modify scheduling properties for processes if the system calls aren't available in c#? Sorry, I don't know that much about windows internals.

Comment: I understand, thank you for taking the time anyways.